# Having a disconnect button and a connect button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have a disconnect button and a connect button on my client. When I click the disconnect button and then the connect button I get this: `OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`

The disconnect button is coded **like this:**

```
def Disconnect():
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    s.close()
```

And the connect button is this:

```
def Join1():
    print("CONNECTING TO: " + host + "...")
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
        print("CONNECTING TO: " + host + " ESTABLISHED!")

        statusbar_status = "Connected"
        startrecv = Thread(target=returnrecv)
        startrecv.start()
```

Why can't I connect again after I click the disconnect button? Is it impossible to reopen the socket? I've been stuck on this problem for like a month now and I can't understand why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After closing a socket, you cannot reuse it to share other data between Server and Client. 
From [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html), about close() method:

> Close the socket. All future operations on the socket object will
>   fail. The remote end will receive no more data (after queued data is
>   flushed). Sockets are automatically closed when they are
>   garbage-collected.

So you would need to create a new socket object every time you try to connect (in your 
`join1()` function which would look something like this:

```
def Join1():
    global s     # i would recommend using classes instead
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)      # your socket object
    print("CONNECTING TO: " + host + "...")
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much, I didn't know about the global keyword! (fairly new to programming). Can you explain why it would be better to use classes instead of global?

Comment: Using global variables in any language is considered "bad". Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil) post. OOP provides a clear modular structure for programs and is much easier to read/write once you get used to it (especially if you're coding GUI app).

Comment: @StevoMitric, I cannot wrap my head around, how to address the same connection object from different controls if we use classes? Even if we have a class with two methods - open and close, how does "close control" see the connection object?